# Detect touch events in Chrome on Windows 8 with touchscreen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, windows-8, jquery

I built a touch/mouse friendly jQuery plugin. It works on phones(ios, android...) and desktops browsers. But i have some issues with Windows 8 Chrome installed on laptop with touch screen. Unfortunately i dont have such a device and cant do any tests.Also IE10 works fine.

Let me explain you what i have inside(very simplified code):

1.Check is touch device:

```
base.isTouch = ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement);
```

2.Get proper events

```
if(base.isTouch === true){
    //use touch events:
    "touchstart.owl",
    "touchmove.owl",
    "touchend.owl"
} else {
    //usemouse events
    "mousedown.owl",
    "mousemove.owl",
    "mouseup.owl"
}
```

3.Check touch events:

```
if(base.isTouch === true){
    x = event.touches[0].pageX
    y = event.touches[0].pageY
} else {
    x = event.pageX
    y = event.pageY
}
```

[link to real code](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js)

I think problem with chrome is that detect my touch events but use mouse events instead and translate them to touch.

I can add mouse and touch events together:

```
$('elem').on('mousedown.owl touchstart.owl',func);
```

Which is OK but then i have a problem with event.touches[0].pageX

[link to plugin landing page](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)

Thanks!

**Problem solved**

To get mouse and touch events working together on windows 8 chrome with touchscreen i had to:

1.add two events on one element "touchstart.owl mousedown.owl"

2.check "event.touches":

```
if(event.touches){
    x = event.touches[0].pageX
    y = event.touches[0].pageY
} else {
    x = event.pageX
    y = event.pageY
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get mouse and touch events working together on windows 8 chrome with touchscreen i had to:

1.add two events on one element "touchstart.owl mousedown.owl"

2.check "event.touches":

```
if(event.touches){
    x = event.touches[0].pageX
    y = event.touches[0].pageY
} else {
    x = event.pageX
    y = event.pageY
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to include Touch Punch plug-in http://touchpunch.furf.com/

I did it for my project and it works well - U can test it, here is my project: 
http://englishtotheworld.com/

Comment: Sorry, obviously if U use JQuery library in Your project.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But i don't want use any other plugins.

Comment: My plugin is based on jQuery library.

Comment: U R welcome. Plug-ins that have been created by JQuery-team programmers, have been tested on various devices, browsers and their versions, I wouldn't recommend U, to create Your own bicycle. Also, U can download the compressed version and include it in 1 file, if U don't want to link another script file.

Comment: Touch Punch is for mobile devices. I have problem with Chrome in Windows 8 on laptop with touchscreen. Touch Punch could be developed by God - i dont care - i asked question about my plugin. BTW your website has problem with mouse dragging in Chrome. thanks