# Touch events not working properly on windows 8 chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-plugins, windows-8, kendo-ui, touch

I'm working on a single page application which have a dashboard where kendo ui widgets (pie chart, bar chart, grid etc ) of variable sized are added by user.

I have used jQuery shapeshift dynamic grid with drag drop functionality to allow user set widgets order as per his/her preferences.

In child container of shapeshift parent element, i.e. in every widget ,there are two links "Settings" and "Remove" to change settings or remove the widget from dashboard.
Everything is working fine in Safari, IE, Firefox but touch events are not working properly on desktop touchscreen using Google chrome with windows 8, like when I clicks on "Settings" or "Remove" links then instead of removing the widget or opening settings dialogue it selects the container to drag, kendo grid paging is not working etc.

It seems that chrome is not interpreting the touch events to appropriate mouse events. I'm searching about the stuff and found this one [Detect touch events in Chrome on Windows 8 with touchscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761078/detect-touch-events-in-chrome-on-windows-8-with-touchscreen) but didn't getting any thing about how to map the events appropriately. Hope problem snapshot will explain the scenario much better.

Any suggestions????

[image]